# return iterated elements from an array

Tags: python, numpy, loops, vector, return

I have this function. I want to return in the form of `(steering, throttle)` for all the elements in the array `vec_steering`. In `(steering, throttle)` throttle value here is constant(1150) and steering changes according to sine curve equation.

```
 def case2():
        vector = np.vectorize(np.int)
        time_interval = 5
        samples = 50
        t = np.linspace(0, time_interval, samples)
        time_req = 5.0
        A = 900
        vec_steering = A*np.sin(2*(np.pi)*t/time_req) + 1024
        vec_steering = vector(vec_steering)
        throttle = 1150
        for s in vec_steering:
            steering, throttle = s, throttle
        return steering, throttle
```

when i run this, I only get the last element for `(steering, throttle)` as `(1023, 1050)` but i want all the values of vec_steering to be iterated and returned. Any insights on this would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Make an array or a generator. Your choice is situation dependent, and you don't provide context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is returning the last element only because after loop iterates through the entire vector, the last element would be stored in the variables steering and throttle and this is what is being returned. To return all the values of the vector, you could iterate through it and store the values in 2 temporary lists(or one 2-D List, whatever works for you) and return the lists. You would then be able to access the list elements individually from the function call.

If you are looking for something like this,

```
def test(n):
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = 2
c = []
return a[n],b

for n in range(5):
print(test(n))
```

Try:

```
 def case2(n):
        vector = np.vectorize(np.int)
        time_interval = 5
        samples = 50
        t = np.linspace(0, time_interval, samples)
        time_req = 5.0
        A = 900
        vec_steering = A*np.sin(2*(np.pi)*t/time_req) + 1024
        vec_steering = vector(vec_steering)
        throttle = 1150
        #returning the nth element , throttle
        return vec_steering[n], throttle
```

Comment: the return i get from this is : `[1024, 1139, 1252, 1361, 1465, 1562, 1650, 1727, 1793, 1846, 1886, 1912, 1923, 1919, 1901, 1868, 1821, 1762, 1690, 1607, 1514, 1414, 1307, 1196, 1081, 966, 851, 740, 633, 533, 440, 357, 285, 226, 179, 146, 128, 124, 135, 161, 201, 254, 320, 397, 485, 582, 686, 795, 908, 1023] [[...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...]]`

Comment: probably you got my question wrong, in the updated code the throttle value also just appends to the list. i am looking to generate paired tuples like (1024, 1150).... (1139, 1150).... where 1150 is throttle(constant) and 1139, 1159 is steering from sine equation

Comment: yes thank you it works.. can i iterate over c to get tuple elements one by one?
basically i want to return (1,2)
(2,2)
(3,2)
.
.

Comment: @siddharth yes you can, give me a sample expected output and I'll try doing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232575/discussion-between-eshaan-gupta-and-siddharth).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution is to return an Nx2 array:

```
def case2():
    steering = (900 * np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 5, 50) / 5.0) + 1024).astype(int)
    throttle = np.full_like(steering, 1150)
    return np.stack((steering, throttle), axis=-1)
```

You can iterate the array as usual with something like

```
for s, t in case2():
    # Do stuff with s and t
```

Better yet, you can perform vectorized operations on the entire array. Keep in mind that `np.vectorize` is a misnomer: it runs a glorified python-level `for` loop.

Another way is to turn your function into a generator:

```
def case2():
    for s in (900 * np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 5, 50) / 5.0) + 1024).astype(int):
        yield s, 1150
```

Using `yield` turns your function into one that returns a generator object, which lets you lazily return the elements of the array in actual tuples. You can iterate over the result just as in the `for` loop shown above, but you will be unable to perform vectorized calculations on a generator.